# Microphone Permission on Firefox Mobile not permanent

Tags: firefox, permissions, getusermedia

I am facing an issue with our web tool that I am unable to solve. I already tried to google a solution but failed to find one.

We have a website where we use JavaScript to record audio from the users microphone via **getUserMedia**. The first time the user enters a html page on the **https** website, there is a notification popping up about permission rights. Thats fine, but on **Firefox** Mobile it doesn't matter if you gave your permission already, you will be asked on every single page again. Thats not the case for every other browser we tried.

So, is this some kind of our error or is it a limitation of Firefox Mobile?
Hope anyone solved that issue already in the past.

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation in [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) (fennec). It intentionally asks users each time.

It's being solved in the next generation version, available in beta as [Firefox Preview](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.fenix) (fenix). The prompt there adds this checkbox, similar to Firefox for desktop:

```
     ☐ Remember decision for this site
```